# How to i change the rewrite rule to read images only

Tags: php, .htaccess

hi all i have this question as my rewrite rule is shown below. But everytime when i am using this code the js file wont work.

```
RewriteRule ^([^thumb].*\.[jJ].*)$ /images/files/w.php?i=$1
```

Can anyone tell me where went wrong?

Comment: By the way, you should go back and accept some of the answers to your questions otherwise people will be less likely to try and answer future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to handle more than just jpgs you can change it to be the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^thumb].*\.(jpe?g|png|gif).*)$ /images/files/w.php?i=$1
```

This will covers `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png` and `gif` file extensions while not matching javascript files.

Note: `[^thumb].*` won't match any file names starting with `t`, `h`, `u`, `m`, or `b`, (e.g., `test.jpg`, `home.jpg`, `umbrella.jpg`, `monster.jpg`, or `beach.jpg` won't match) not just files starting with `thumb...`, for the whole word, `thumb`, you need a negative lookahead `(?!regex)`. To make the rule not match files starting with "thumb" this is what the rule should look like:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!thumb).*\.(jpe?g|png|gif).*)$ /images/files/w.php?i=$1
```

One last problem the rule handles text after the file extension which I assume means that you may have urls that look like:

`http://www.example.com/test.png?foo=a&b=baz`

Your rule will create a rewrite that ends up looking like

`http://www.example.com/images/files/w.php?i=test.png?a=foo&b=baz`

Which is not a valid url as there are now two `?`s in the query string. To fix this I'd go with the following regex.

```
RewriteRule ^((?!thumb).*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))\??(.*)$ /images/files/w.php?i=$1&$2
```

This regexp rule will result in a properly formed url

`http://www.example.com/images/files/w.php?i=test.png&a=foo&b=baz`

Comment: hi i got this working perfectly. but how do i make the initial to have watermark in the specific folder only ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty 'solution', since you obviously want to separate jpeg and js:

```
RewriteRule ^([^thumb].*\.[jJ][pP].*)$ /images/files/w.php?i=$1
```